# How can you tell what Tables are taking up the most space in a SQL Server 2005 Database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

How can you tell what Tables are taking up the most space in a SQL Server 2005 Database?

I am sure there is some System Stored Procedure that shows this information.

I have a TEST database that grew from 1tb to 23tb. We are currently doing a lot of client conversion testing in the database, which entails running the same conversion Stored Procedure multiple times. It does DELETEs which I am sure is increasing the Transaction Log. But this got me thinking to ask this question.

## info

the big problem is the dbo.Download table, it creates massive storage that is actually not needed, I had 3GB before truncating it, then 52MB ;)

Comment: Marc_S and Barry's answers where just outstanding so I upvoted both of them and was waiting to see which one got the most upvotes so I could reward that one with the "Accepted Answer". But they were both tied at 5 so I just picked one but I used both. Thank you very much Marc_S and Barry!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get size of all tables in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892334/get-size-of-all-tables-in-database)

Answer (score 238, accepted):

Try this script - it will list the number of rows and the space used by data rows (and the total space used) for all tables in your database:

```
SELECT 
 t.NAME AS TableName,
 i.name AS indexName,
 SUM(p.rows) AS RowCounts,
 SUM(a.total_pages) AS TotalPages, 
 SUM(a.used_pages) AS UsedPages, 
 SUM(a.data_pages) AS DataPages,
 (SUM(a.total_pages) * 8) / 1024 AS TotalSpaceMB, 
 (SUM(a.used_pages) * 8) / 1024 AS UsedSpaceMB, 
 (SUM(a.data_pages) * 8) / 1024 AS DataSpaceMB
FROM 
 sys.tables t
INNER JOIN  
 sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
INNER JOIN 
 sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
INNER JOIN 
 sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
WHERE 
 t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%' AND
 i.OBJECT_ID > 255 AND  
 i.index_id <= 1
GROUP BY 
 t.NAME, i.object_id, i.index_id, i.name 
ORDER BY 
 OBJECT_NAME(i.object_id)
```

Comment: +1 Brilliant.  Note that this doesn't include the size of data indices.  For me, though, it got the job done.

Comment: I didn't know this, but if you're using Management Studio you can also right click on the database and go to Reports -> Disk Usage by Table for the same results.

Comment: @rossisdead, that's hilarious piece of information to know. Thanks!

Comment: I get 'Table 'sys.tables' doesn't exist'

Comment: @Seano: what SQL Server version are you using? (run `SELECT @@VERSION` to find out) What database compatibility level does your database have??

Comment: I had to add `a.type != 3` to the WHERE clause to avoid Row_Overflow rows from being double counted in the row counts.  Not sure if this will break the Space counts, as apparently my overflow rows are empty.

Answer (score 37):

Use [sp_spacedUsed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188776.aspx)

`Exec sp_spaceused N'YourTableName'`

Or if you want to execute the `sp_spaceused` for each table in your database then you can use this SQL:

```
set nocount on
create table #spaceused (
  name nvarchar(120),
  rows char(11),
  reserved varchar(18),
  data varchar(18),
  index_size varchar(18),
  unused varchar(18)
)

declare Tables cursor for
  select name
  from sysobjects where type='U'
  order by name asc

OPEN Tables
DECLARE @table varchar(128)

FETCH NEXT FROM Tables INTO @table

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  insert into #spaceused exec sp_spaceused @table
  FETCH NEXT FROM Tables INTO @table
END

CLOSE Tables
DEALLOCATE Tables 

select * from #spaceused
drop table #spaceused

exec sp_spaceused
```

The above SQL is from [here](http://www.cryer.co.uk/brian/sqlserver/howto_list_table_sizes.htm)

Comment: For newer versions of SQL Server you can also use `exec sp_msforeachtable 'exec sp_spaceused N''?'''`

Comment: @JNK `sp_msforeachtable` exists since at least SQl Server 2000

Comment: @SQLMenace - thanks for the info.  I didn't research how old it was before posting, but wasn't sure I would find it since it's undocumented.

Comment: A _slightly_ simpler example: You can get away with skipping the EXECs and fancy quoting, by doing just `sp_msforeachtable 'sp_spaceused [?]'` if you like. Verified back to SQL2000.

Comment: Mark problem with this method is it doesn't return as a single result set

Comment: If you are using non-default schema, this query won't work. To fix it you can change the cursor query to `select TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME as name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES order by TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME`.

Answer (score 12):

Rossisdead's comment answered this question the best for me, I wish it wasn't buried in a comment.  This will be useful for people like me not trying to script the solution (the OP did **not** ask for a code snippet)

> If you're using Management Studio you can also right click on the
>   database and go to Reports -> Disk Usage by Table for the same
>   results

Comment: For emphasis: right click the **Database** and not the **Server Instance**

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to [@marc_s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3927275/1501497) for the answer. I needed to know data vs index space so I went ahead and expanded on the query to include that.

```
SELECT TableName
    , SUM(DataRowCounts) AS DataRowCounts
    , SUM(DataTotalSpaceGB) AS DataTotalSpaceGB
    , SUM(DataSpaceUsedGB) AS DataSpaceUsedGB
    , SUM(DataUnusedSpaceGB) AS DataUnusedSpaceGB
    , SUM(IndexRowCounts) AS IndexRowCounts
    , SUM(IndexTotalSpaceGB) AS IndexTotalSpaceGB
    , SUM(IndexSpaceUsedGB) AS IndexSpaceUsedGB
    , SUM(IndexUnusedSpaceGB) AS IndexUnusedSpaceGB
    , SUM(DataTotalSpaceGB) + SUM(IndexTotalSpaceGB) AS TotalSpaceGB
FROM
(
SELECT t.NAME AS TableName
    , i.type_desc AS IndexType
    , CASE WHEN i.type_desc IN ('CLUSTERED', 'CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE', 'HEAP') THEN CAST(ROUND(((SUM(a.total_pages) * 8) / 1024.00), 2)/1000 AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) ELSE 0 END AS DataTotalSpaceGB
    , CASE WHEN i.type_desc IN ('CLUSTERED', 'CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE', 'HEAP') THEN CAST(ROUND(((SUM(a.used_pages) * 8) / 1024.00), 2)/1000 AS NUMERIC(36, 2))  ELSE 0 END AS DataSpaceUsedGB    
    , CASE WHEN i.type_desc IN ('CLUSTERED', 'CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE', 'HEAP') THEN CAST(ROUND(((SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) * 8) / 1024.00, 2)/1000 AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) ELSE 0 END AS DataUnusedSpaceGB
    , CASE WHEN i.type_desc IN ('CLUSTERED', 'CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE', 'HEAP') THEN SUM(p.Rows) ELSE 0 END AS DataRowCounts
    , CASE WHEN i.type_desc = 'NONCLUSTERED' THEN CAST(ROUND(((SUM(a.total_pages) * 8) / 1024.00), 2)/1000 AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) ELSE 0 END AS IndexTotalSpaceGB
    , CASE WHEN i.type_desc = 'NONCLUSTERED' THEN CAST(ROUND(((SUM(a.used_pages) * 8) / 1024.00), 2)/1000 AS NUMERIC(36, 2))  ELSE 0 END AS IndexSpaceUsedGB    
    , CASE WHEN i.type_desc = 'NONCLUSTERED' THEN CAST(ROUND(((SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) * 8) / 1024.00, 2)/1000 AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) ELSE 0 END AS IndexUnusedSpaceGB  
    , CASE WHEN i.type_desc = 'NONCLUSTERED' THEN SUM(p.Rows) ELSE 0 END AS IndexRowCounts
FROM sys.tables t
INNER JOIN sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
INNER JOIN sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
LEFT JOIN sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%'
    AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND i.OBJECT_ID > 255
    AND s.Name = 'dbo' --update this filter
    AND t.Name = 'MyTable'
GROUP BY t.Name
    , i.type_desc
) x
GROUP BY TableName
ORDER BY TotalSpaceGB DESC
```