# How to determine why a Table is using so much space?

Tags: sql-server

I've encountered a very weird table which I can not understand.
It Consists of just four Columns, two ints and two varchar(64).
Only 1000 rows are contained, but the storage used is over 6GB!
There is no tracking enabled and Index space is lenn than 1MB.

How can I find out why this thing is consumping that much space and how would I be able to fix this?

**EDIT:** sp_spaceused result

```
Table1  1264 8642024KB  6916872KB   552KB   1724600KB
```

Comment: how do you know its 6GB in size ?

Comment: Did you delete many rows from trust table? What if you create a new take with the same structure and copy the date there?

Comment: Can you include the output of sp_spaceused

Comment: Properties -> Storage or using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927231/how-can-you-tell-what-tables-are-taking-up-the-most-space-in-a-sql-server-2005-d

Comment: It could be deleted rows, like @DrPhil suggested

Comment: Try to run the command: `ALTER TABLE [YourWeirdTableName] REBUILD;` and then check its size again.

Comment: That reduced the size to basicly nothing, but what caused it and how to prevent that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have clustered index on table? If not, it's heap table. When rows are deleted from a heap the Database Engine may use row or page locking for the operation. As a result, the pages made empty by the delete operation remain allocated to the heap. When empty pages are not deallocated, the associated space cannot be reused by other objects in the database.
[MSDN t-sql DELETE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/delete-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#locking-behavior)

To reduce size try this one:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable REBUILD;
ALTER INDEX ALL ON MyTable REBUILD WITH (FILLFACTOR = 100);
```

Comment: An excellent article on this topic: [DELETE Operation in SQL Server HEAPs](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/delete-operation-sql-server-heaps/)

Comment: would ALTER INDEX ALL ON MyTable REBUILD include the rebuild on the table itself?

Comment: @Jaster You are right, you need rebuild table before rebuild index. Answer updated